# bridging two wireless interfaces - possible?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, wireless-bridge

What I am trying to do is simple.

1. create a bridge => br0
2. add first Wi-Fi nic => wlan0
3. add second Wi-Fi nic => wlan1

so I end up with br0 = wlan0+wlan1.

Yet, I always get this error msg: *operation not supported* (using **brctl**)

I lately flashed my router with DD-WRT and put it in bridge repeater mode. It's is exactly what I wanted to do ages ago with my Linux machine.

Any idea what was I doing wrong? and why dd-wrt can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this as well and failed. But I did find this (note: I have not tried this solution yet, but appears to be what we're looking for): http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw#Using_4-address_for_AP_and_client_mode

If you are successful, please post back.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.